# Cannot find lpc1768 specific FreeRTOS-Plus libraries

Tags: embedded, freertos, cmsis

I inherited a project that is built on lpc1768-based hardware. This was not used for years and the original developers left the company.

The project uses FreeRTOS, CMSIS library for the lpc1768 and FreeRTOS-Plus components for the lpc1786.  We run into problems when we tried to upgrade the components to their current versions.

That was successful for the FreeRTOS core. But for the CMSIS and the FreeRTOS-Plus source code we run into problems and could not even identify from where these parts of the source once were once downloaded.

We have a group of source files named FreeRTOS_lpc17xx_can.c, FreeRTOS_lpc17xx_uart.c, FreeRTOS_lpc17xx_DriverInterface.c, etc. One can find even some references to some of the filenames in Google, but we had no success to identify the product these files belong to. The copyright header points to 'Real time engineers' which is FreeRTOS, but on their site we found nothing for lpc1768. After that we checked if these files are available from NXP and did not find anithing either.

Can someone explain from where these files are available?

A second group of source code where we have the same problem is CMSIS.  Again, we have a lot of CMSIS sourcecode (this time with ARM copyright headers, but again we cannot identify where these files are offered. We expected them to be part of the openLpc libraries from NXP but where not able to find openLpc for lpc1768.

Thus the same question: Who offers the CMSIS lpc1768 interfaces and where can we download them?

Comment: Surely it would be simpler to _not_ upgrade the components and treat the code as a legacy system in maintenance.  It may even include customisation and modifications specific to your project and target that were never in the original source code that you would loose if you simply replaced it with later versions.  What toolchain are you using? Keil uVision has DevPacks for CMSIS down to v3.20.  The `.pack` files are in any case simply ZIP files with a different extension and can be unpacked without uVision https://www.keil.com/dd2/pack/

Comment: [FreeRTOS+](https://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-Plus/index.shtml) is not a product, but rather a collection of FreeRTOS Ecosystem projects from multiple sources.  Pick the + project components relevant to your application (if they still exist).  One of teh + components are BSPs for various targets - perhaps you need https://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-Plus/BSP_Solutions/NXP/index.html for example.

Comment: Since this is more-or-less a LMGTFY question and is certainly off-topic as a "help me find a library" question, and possibly also too broad, I have not posted an answer (and voted to close) , but hope the comments are nonetheless helpful.

Comment: https://www.nxp.com/support/developer-resources/software-development-tools/lpc-developer-resources-/lpcopen-libraries-and-examples/lpcopen-software-development-platform-lpc17xx:LPCOPEN-SOFTWARE-FOR-LPC17XX    some stuff here but seriously dated.

Comment: @Clifford:  The existing code is a POC, representing the start for a new system thus not legacy. Since we want a clean start, we need to identify the libraries used.

Comment: @Clifford: We google now the second day.  The paradox is that all Links sooner or later come to a dead end, as the links provided by you and Realtime Rik prove. We did know both of them, but you will not find lpc1768 libs.

Comment: Did you also look at the Kiel DFP?https://www.keil.com/dd2/nxp/lpc1768/  You did not answer the question about what tool-chain.  I doubt the exact components you need will necessarily be drop-in replacements - you may have to do some work.  You failes to specify the toolchain - often, as is the case with Keil and IAR, the part specific files come from the toolchain vendor.

Comment: Also https://www.nxp.com/support/developer-resources/software-development-tools/lpc-developer-resources-/lpcopen-libraries-and-examples:LPC-OPEN-LIBRARIES

Comment: @Clifford The toolchain is GNU ARM Eclipse OpenOCD (https://gnu-mcu-eclipse.github.io/openocd/) plus the GCC ARM Embedded Toolchain (https://developer.arm.com/open-source/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm).

Comment: @MichaelB : Free tools are only free if your time is worth nothing perhaps? I suggest you seek out libraries with equivalent function, and port your application to them, rather than looking for exact API equivalence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A current version of the CMSIS library can be found at [lpc175x_6x_cmsis_driver_library_0.zip](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qdtXqvLqQoIKSMrtabgRIH5fCs94qsPv). In case this link does not work, follow https://community.nxp.com/message/1014233?commentID=1014233#comment-1014233.

FreeRTOS+IO including besides others a CAN and I2C driver can be found at [GitHub](https://github.com/barathbushan/CanDriverOnFreeRTOS).